# JavaScript Function Issue (dates)

Tags: javascript, date, scope, onclick, dom-events

I'm having issues with my JavaScript code. I need to make code that does the following:

1. Click an image twice within 3 seconds to make the image disappear
2. Click it once to reappear

I've got it close to working...I'm just having issues with the date. I don't know how to keep the date from the first click. My code right now is just creating a new start date each click which is what I don't want.

Code thus far:

```
var imgNext = -1;
var start = new Date ( );

function disappear ()
{
 var end = new Date ();
 imgNext++;

if (imgNext == 2)
{
    document.getElementById("myPicture").style.visibility="visible";
    imgNext = -1;
}
if (imgNext == 1 && (end-start <3000))
{
    document.getElementById("myPicture").style.visibility="hidden";
}
start = new Date ();
```

}

In the code the image changes even if the clicks are over 3 seconds apart because I'm creating a new START date every time the function is triggered. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You just need to declare it outside of the `disappear` function, just as you did with `imgNext`.

Comment: But if I declare outside the function that will create a new start ONLY once when the browser is loaded? And if I then click the image twice within 3 seconds it may not work if I've waited more than 3 seconds since the browser loaded.

Comment: You just create a local, new one, compare it with the previous, act accordingly, and then assign the current date to the global variable.

Comment: I've had an attempt at that, and I edited my code in original post above. It's working but I'm still having bugs after I wait the 3 seconds. It's close...though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer, with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/yS5bs/2/

```
document.getElementById("disappear").onclick = function() {
    var lastClick = this.attributes["click-time"],
        click = new Date().getTime(),
        timeout = parseInt(this.attributes["data-timeout"].value);

        if(lastClick && (click - lastClick) < timeout && this.style.opacity == 1) {
            this.style.opacity = 0;
            this.attributes["click-time"].value = null;
            return;
        }
        else {
            this.attributes["click-time"] = click;
        }

        if(this.style.opacity == 0) {
            this.style.opacity = 1;
            this.attributes["click-time"] = null;
            return;
        }
};
```

basically I am assigning the onclick, and getting the click times, if within the set timeout (milliseconds) then it hides, otherwise, it shows again, as per spec

Comment: not a problem! to change the interval, just change the attribute :)